# Is there a verse about "big" and "small" lies being the same in God's kingdom?

Tags: lying

I am looking for a certain verse or passage.

The one I'm looking for contains statements about there being no such thing as a "small" lie or "big" lie and that lies are all the same in God's kingdom.

Comment: I don't think you'll find such a statement strictly about lies (in a typical protestant Bible). All sin is equated as being equally sinful, but even that is a conclusion based on the Biblical authors' treatment of sin, not a statement saying "murder is just as sinful as lying." If you have a specific canon in mind, you could add that to the question or as a tag.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types. I don't think it's quite off-topic, but it's not a very good question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is making the Bible say what you want, rather than learning what the Bible says.

Comment: No, this is a good question. This is like "story identification" over in SciFi.SE. This is great. I'm glad the OP is wanting to verify if her cultural idioms are in the bible or not.

Comment: This question has generated a meta issue: [Where's the line with the "verse-identification" tag?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4199)

Comment: [I favor that such questions are off-topic](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4199/wheres-the-line-with-the-verse-identification-tag#comment10351_4200), so I have voted to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because of reasons being discussed here: [Where's the line with the "verse-identification" tag?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4199)

Answer (score 4):

This might be the idea you're going for:

> **James 2:10-11 ESV** For whoever keeps the whole law and yet stumbles at just one point is guilty of breaking all of it. For he who said, “You shall not commit adultery,” also said, “You shall not murder.” If you do not commit adultery but do commit murder, you have become a lawbreaker.

*"...just one point..."* being the key statement. If you tell a "small lie" but don't tell a "big" one, you are just as much a law breaker before God because your heart intended to deceive in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly 1 John 2:21

> 21 I have not written unto you because ye know not the truth, but because ye know it, and that no lie is of the truth.

That declares that No lie is of the truth. That's the only one I can find. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If "lie" was replaced with "sin", then perhaps you are after:

Matthew 5:27-28

> 27Ye have heard that it was said by them of old time, Thou shalt not commit adultery: 28But I say unto you, That whosoever looketh on a woman to lust after her hath committed adultery with her already in his heart.

Matthew 5:21-22

> 21Ye have heard that it was said by them of old time, Thou shalt not kill; and whosoever shall kill shall be in danger of the judgment: 22But I say unto you, That whosoever is angry with his brother without a cause shall be in danger of the judgment: and whosoever shall say to his brother, Raca, shall be in danger of the council: but whosoever shall say, Thou fool, shall be in danger of hell fire.

Answer (score -3):

My favourite verse is found in the Book of Mormon; Another Testament of Jesus Christ:

[2 Nephi 9:24;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/9.34?lang=eng#33)

> ## "Wo unto the liar, for he shall be thrust down to hell."

There is also [Proverbs 19:9;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/prov/19.9?lang=eng#8)

> **"A false witness shall not be unpunished, and he that speaketh lies
>   shall perish."**

There's not exactly a whole lot of wiggle room in those verses.

Comment: Haters gunna hate, Mormons gunna orate.